# Filtering tables using worksheet variables

Tags: vba, filter, listobject

I'm trying to filter a table and then copy a value, different filter, different value. Rinse and repeat.
I've recorded a macro to help me along and that looks like:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
        "Lopend"
```

When I replace activesheet with my declared `ws` variable (it works, I see the value in the locale) I get error 9, subscript out of range.

```
wsReo.ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="Lopend"
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: edit: changed the l in 1. Now I get : "error 9, subscript out of range"

Comment: Does the collection wsReo.ListObjects have something named "Tabel1" as a member? or is it called "Table1"?

Comment: Well, it showed up during record macro. Tabel is the Dutch word for Table (in this particular instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `Criteria1` not `Criterial`

the number 1, not an L.

Comment: fixed. Leads to subscript out of range.

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by Brax's comment about criteria1. However, the undelying problem was that I set the wrong `ws` variable to the wrong `ws` (I swapped them).